# Rails 4.2.5: strange behavior of before_action with passenger vs webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passenger

Below are my controllers with before_action

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  #
  # ....
  #
end

class Admin::DashboardController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "dashboard#show"  # to match the route /admin
  end
```

I am using devise for authentication. The problem when used with passenger 5.0.23 is when I first access /admin from browser without login, I am redirected to /admins/sign_in which is perfect. Without logging in if I again try to access /admin, it takes me to the dashboard. So the before_action is being ignored. Now if I modify any of the above controller or restart passenger, the before_action works again for the immediate request to /admin but not for the subsequent requests.

I tried with passenger 5.0.15 which is working fine with another application of rails 4.1.5, but it didnt solve the problem. I couldn't try downgrading rails to 4.1.5 as it raised lot of other errors.

When I run the same above application with webrick, before_action works fine every time.

Is there anyone who is facing the above issue? Any idea what could be the reason for the above issue and any suggestions to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
The issue seems to exist when used with webrick as well. I have 2 types of authentication. One is for user and the other one for admin. With webrick the issue toggles between the two authentications. If before_action works for authenticate_user!, it doesn't work for authenticate_admin! and vice versa. Where as with passenger it works with neither. This seems to be happening only in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for the problem. I renamed Admin::ApplicationController to Admin::BaseController and inherited it in all admin controllers. The before_filters are now working as expected, but still not sure why it was wrong to have Admin::ApplicationController. Is the class name 'ApplicationController' confusing to the ruby interpreter? Because the inheritence hierarchy was:

```
 Admin::DashboardController < Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
```

So for Admin::DashboardController, it seems to appear there is only one ApplicationController and ignores Admin::ApplicationController. May be!